# Devise - How do I forbid certain users from signing in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for authentication in my application.

How do I forbid certain users from signing in - kind of disable a user?

Comment: This is a valid question and should be reopened - OP is asking "How do I forbid certain users from signing in" using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Do it like this:

Create a column called `is_active` for the `User` model.

Then add the code below to the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this method is called by devise to check for "active" state of the model
  def active_for_authentication?
    #remember to call the super
    #then put our own check to determine "active" state using 
    #our own "is_active" column
    super and self.is_active?
  end
end
```

*UPDATE*

As Matt Huggins notes, the method is now called `active_for_authentication?` ([Documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable))

Comment: Looks like this has been renamed to `active_for_authentication?` instead of just `active?`.

Comment: `the method is now called active_for_authentication?` means that your method name should be `active_for_authentication?` instead of `active?`.

Comment: Devise Wiki - [How to customize user account status validation when logging in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in)

Comment: Important note: `active_for_authentication?` has to be a public method!

Comment: `super and self.is_active?` can be simplified to `super && is_active?`

Comment: To customize the error message, see the Devise docs here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in#customize-error-message

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is what exactly i was searching.

Answer (score 26):

Add a column to the `User` model: `allowed_to_log_in`.

Then add this to `/app/models/user.rb`:

```
def active_for_authentication?
    super and self.allowed_to_log_in?
end
```

If you want to inform the user with a custom message you can add this as well:

```
def inactive_message
    "You are not allowed to log in."
end
```

I think that is quite important because the standard message from Devise says:

> "Your account is not activated yet."

That is confusing for users and the real reason is that you have "banned" them from logging in.

Comment: I am implementing a user suspension feature which works however the inactive_message "Your account is currently suspended" is displayed for now user signups too. Can I have different inactive messages for new account activation and user suspension?

Comment: http://kiprosh.com/blog/customizing-devise-authentication-to-disable-or-enable-user-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the inactive_message comment.

Comment: I have defined same method as you mentioned here. but devise default message is showing. I am expecting custom message for inactive account. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do authorization, not authentication. Devise only does authetication, though.
I.e. devise only tells you that a user is who he says he is.
You need something else to forbid him from using the site.

Authorization is a popular topic and there's a whole list of gems that can help you with it:
http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html
Take your pick.

Comment: I know the difference. The thing is that I want to forbid the user to signin, not accessing certain controller.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you may be interested in cancan

- https://github.com/ryanb/cancan
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question asked. Most people know the difference between authorization and authentication. The question was how do you make it so a user can't login.